# Parse.com redirect user depending on whether he's logged in or not (Express server)

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, parse-platform

I'm building a web app using Parse.com Express server and I'd like to redirect a user depending on whether he's logged in or not on the server side.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it with Passport.js handling the session and loading the user for me.
If you are using another method, you may need to test something different than `if(req.user)`.

```
function redirectIfAnon(req, res, next){
  if(req.user){
    return next(); // go to next handling function in middleware chain
  } else {
    var dest = encodeURIComponent(req.originalUrl);
    res.redirect('/login?bounce='+dest)
    // careful about redirect loops here... if you apply this middleware to /login,
    // and an anonymous user visits /login, it will keep redirecting to /login
  };
};

app.get('/test',
redirectIfAnon,
function(req, res){
  // req.user is guranteed to be populated if we get here
  parse.fetch(req.user.parseID, function(err...){
    ...
    // or something. ive never used parse.com
    res.render('parseResults');
  })
});
```